# $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is cauchy if and only if $d(x_{n_k},x_{m_k}) \rightarrow 0$ for any two sequences $n_k, m_k \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to know if the following assertion is correct:

> If $(M,d)$ is a metric space, then $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is cauchy if and only if $d(x_{n_k},x_{m_k}) \rightarrow 0$ for any two sequences of natural numbers $n_k, m_k \rightarrow \infty$

Of course the direction from left to right is true. But I am unsure of the direction from  right to left. Can anyone give a proof or state a counterexample?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I'd assume the sequence of the distances to tend to $0$ instead of $\infty$ for a Cauchy series!

Comment: Oh yes, that was a typo. Do you know how to check if this is true?

Comment: Just the negation of $(x_n)$ being Cauchy. You will get the implication from right to left easily.

Answer (score 0):

Since the right side is true for any sequences $n_k$ and $m_k$, simply take $n_k=k$ and  $m_k=k+1$ and conclude.